# How to run custom validation function in the joi schema

Tags: javascript, validation, schema, joi

I want to make a field mandatory or optional based on something that is not in the schema. For example, something stored in the global scope. This is the Joi schema:

```
first_name: Joi.string().min(2).max(10).regex(Regex.alphabeta, 'alphabeta').error(JoiCustomErrors)
```

How to make `first_name` be required if `some_global_scope_var` is 1, else, make it optional?

Note: `some_global_scope_var` is not part of the schema.

Comment: is my answer working for you? Do you need further help?

Answer (score 0):

#### Access Global scope with `$` character

Normally you would access a relative property `last_name` without a prefix. For global access prefix your variable with `$`.

#### Complete Solution

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

global.app = {
  someValue: 1,
};

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  first_name: Joi.string()
                 .min(2)
                 .max(10)
                 .when('$app.someValue', {
                   is: Joi.equal(1),
                   then: Joi.required(),
                 })
});

const value = {
  first_name: 'a1300',
};

const result = schema.validate(value);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result.error, null, 2));
```

> P.S. I omitted `regex(Regex.alphabeta, 'alphabeta').error(JoiCustomErrors)`